# Cloud9 C++ Breakpoints

Tags: c++, cloud9-ide, cloud9, aws-cloud9

**Edit:** I tried using the breakpoints built into the editor on a very simple program and it works. So it's possible my code (used a good deal of the instance's memory) plus the debugger was too much for the nano instance.

I've been using gdb on the command line for debugging and breakpoints. But it looks like Cloud9 has a nice built-in debugger.

Adding a breakpoint and running the C++ in "debug" mode, yields the following:

[image]

Has anyone been able to use breakpoints and the visual debugger in cloud9 for c++?

I've tried writing a few custom runners for valgrind, etc. But this is using the standard c++ runner.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your code compiled without -ggdb3 option as warning in output says.

Could you try to remove your objects files as it suggests and run file again?

It worked for me on simple Hello World example

Comment: hm, I took a look at the default C++ runner, and the line is as follows: `g++ -ggdb3 -std=c++11 $file -o $file.o`

Comment: So it was definitely running with the flag, but I tried on a simple Hello World example like you mentioned and it worked there. Thanks for the tip on trying that. Still doesn't work on my original code though.